# QueryParameterException could not locate named parameter with none Entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

My project setting are Spring MVC, Hibernate 4.3.8.Final, on PostgreSQL DB and getting the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [username]

```java
public UserInfo findUserInfo(String userName) {
    String sql = "Select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username,u.password) "//
            + " from " + User.class.getName() + " u where u.username=(:username)";

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("username", userName);

    return (UserInfo) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

With **UserInfo** is none entity:

```java
public class UserInfo {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public UserInfo() {
    }

    public UserInfo(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because I'm not already declaring my entity with Hibernate configure file.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have an entity called `User` replace `"from " + User.class.getName()` with `"from yourpackage." + User.class.getName()` and remove the parenthesis around your parameter`(:username)`; it should be `:username`.

So your string should be like below:

```
 String sql = "Select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username,u.password) "
            + " from yourpackageHERE." + User.class.getName() + " u where u.username=:username";
```

But if your entity is called `UserInfo` then make sure to use `UserInfo` in both the `select` and the `from`.

```
String sql = "Select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username,u.password) "
                + " from yourpackageHERE." + UserInfo.class.getName() + " u where u.username=:username";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But UserInfo is normal Class (non-entity) and User is entity which is mapping on table user.

Comment: @GiangPhanThanhGiang then use `String sql = "Select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username,u.password) "
            + " from yourpackageHERE." + User.class.getName() + " u where u.username=:username";`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found my problem. Because I'm not aldready declare my entity with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract from the [JPA 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf):

> ## 4.3.1 Naming
>
> Entities are designated in query strings by their entity names. The entity name is defined by the name element of the Entity annotation (or the entity-name XML descriptor element), and defaults to the unqualified name of the entity class. Entity names are scoped within the persistence unit and must be unique within the persistence unit.

So according to the extract of the Spec above, your query string should be :

```
String sql = "select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username, u.password) from User u where u.username=:username";
```

Assuming you have defined an entity `User`, `User.class.getName()` returns a qualified name (including package name) of the class whereas JPA requires unqualified name of the entity. The other thing is, as user @Mitchapp pointed out, no parentheses are allowed around the named parameter.

Comment: I removed parentheses are allowed around the named parameter, but it's also not working

Comment: What do you get? Any exception? I think you are mixing things. If you are using JPA use `EntityManager` instead of `Session`. The above query is not HQL but JP QL, which means you better use EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager to define your query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found my problem, My Entitiy is out side of package which is scaned by factory Bean.

Comment: `LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean(); factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "mypackage.entity" });`